# How do I forward emails in thunderbird in a format other than .eml?

Tags: thunderbird, file-format

When I forward emails in tbird, they are attached as .eml files.

Some recipients can't open these files. How do I forward emails in a different file format? e.g., as text files perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default forward method in Thunderbird](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230448) is inline. To [change back to the default](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1156638), open the Thunderbird Preferences, and go to the Composition page, General tab and set `Forward messages` to inline.

To just forward the current email as inline and leave the default, use "Message->Forward As->Inline"